# Avoiding geo-blocking with SSH tunneling

Tags: ssh, proxy, ip, tunnel

I live in UK and I need a Spanish IP to access some content on the internet.

I rented a VPS server based in Spain, which has a Spanish IP.

Now I folowed [this tutorial](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Easy_SSH_tunnels) to create a SSH tunnel to my VPS, so that I can configure firefox to use it as a proxy to connect to websites.

I now go to whatsmyip.com and I can see the Spanish IP, so it seems everything is working fine, right? In fact if I go to wheremyipaddress.com, it says I am in Spain... But I can't access the restricted content anyway! And I've tried a couple of different restricted sites without success...

Do you know what this could be due to? Any ideas?
Maybe the websites can detect that you're using a proxy and they don't like that?

---

EDIT: I've checked and when I **do not** use the proxy the error message says "*Not available in your region*". 
However, if I **do** use the proxy, the message is something like "*Connection refused*"
So, probably the website is detecting I'm using a proxy, right? Is there any way to avoid sites blocking you when using a proxy?

Comment: The content that you're trying to access may block, by default, requests that are proxied.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the proxy settings from inside Control Panel/Preferences or just in the browser? If you're using some kind of applet (java, flash etc) it might not be using the browser's proxy but instead skipping straight out from your IP address as there is no system proxy set.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS queries default to being done locally (not through the SOCKS proxy) which can cause problems with some services that geo locate.

For Firefox you can set it to do DNS queries over the SOCKS proxy:

- Go to the URL "about:config"
- Find the setting "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns" and set it to "true"

There is also an Add-on for Firefox called FoxyProxy that while riddled with upsells is free as a Standard version which can send traffic to different proxies or no proxy based on URL patterns along with a setting per proxy of using remote DNS.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, but I set the configuration as you said but it is still not working, any other ideas?

Comment: I've checked and when I do not use the proxy the error message says "Not available in your country", and if I do use the proxy the message is like "connection refused"... so probably the website is detecting I'm using a proxy, right? Is there any way to avoid sites blocking you when using a proxy?